# Rails 3 - Delayed_Job (collectiveidea), trying to Delay Mailers - Error: NoMethodError (undefined method `delay' for UserMailer:Class)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I'm using the delayed_job gem here: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

I have the following in an observer:

```
UserMailer.delay.msg_notification(record)
```

In user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base 
... 
def msg_notification(record) 
    mail( 
          :to => "#{record.user.email}", 
          :subject => "Notification" 
          ) 
  end 
.. 
end
```

But this errors with:

```
 NoMethodError (undefined method `delay' for UserMailer:Class):
```

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: have you double checked to make sure that the gem is in your gem file, and you have run bundle install. Also have you already created the backend tables the gem requires as outlined in the documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen a problem like this on our Rails app (2.3.8, but the issue sounds the same).  Basically, there are three ways to delay an action:

1. `MyClass.delay.foo(arg)`
2. Putting `handle_asynchronously :foo` in your class definition after the definition of foo
3. `MyClass.send_later(:foo, arg)`

For whatever reason, #3 was the only form that worked consistently across all our development machines.  #1 died on our development server (Ubuntu); #2 on our designer's Mac.  But #3 was fine.

Hope that helps!

Comment: [DEPRECATION] `object.send_later(:method)` is deprecated. Use `object.delay.method` but it's still not working for me

Comment: @Lucas  I've only tried this with Rails 2.3.8, so what you're seeing might be a Rails 3 thing.  Or you could try a different fork of delayed_job - there are bunches (we use CollectiveIdea's, I think).  Or it might just be deprecated across the board - which would be terrible news, 'cause `send_later` was the only one that consistently worked!  Perhaps a bug report is in order...

Answer (score 2):

Also check if you have restarted your server after the bundle install. That could be a issue too...